# How to make last row take the rest height of container?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a parent container with `display: grid`, which is a flex item, I explicitly defined 2 rows within this grid. How do I make my last row take up remain of the container? I tried `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr` but it doesn't work.

Here's some reference code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:borderbox;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

header {
  min-height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
    z-index: 999;
    flex: auto 0 auto;
}

.main-grid {
  display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "title title title"
                        "left content right";
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.grid-title {
  grid-area: title;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-left {
  grid-area: left;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.grid-right {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: cyan;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-top: auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header> Some nav, NOT part of grid</header>
  <div class="main-grid">
    <div class="grid-title">Title, IS part of grid</div>
    <div class="grid-content">Main content that should take up all availabe  green space below which is the container.
    </div>
    <div class="grid-left">Left of grid</div>
    <div class="grid-right">Right of grid</div>
  </div>
  <footer> Some footer, NOT part of grid</footer>
</body>
```

As you see, my container for the grid expanded to the footer, but the last row of the grid doesn't follow. How do I fix it? Is there a way to set `grid-template-rows`? Specifically, I want the first row to take as much height as it wants, and the rest is for the second row.
I'm using Chrome 87.

Comment: Change `min-height: 100vh;` to `height: 100vh;`

Comment: @Paulie_D Aiyyyy, it worked, thanks brother.